# Is there a way to preserve EXIF data when converting file from JPG to PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, photo-editing, jpg

I have following requirements:

- Convert JPG image to transparent PNG
- Preserve the tags given in JPG image and have it in PNG image as well.

When I convert JPG image to transparent PNG, the EXIF data (tags data) is lost.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: I found my answer here. Please check below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg

Comment: Could you summarize that in an answer here so that this question doesn't hang around as unanswered?